# Java String Class matches Method

Tags: java, regex, string

My Program is

```
public class EHFix {
static String regExpCharacter = "(.*)HI(.*)";
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String val="HI  How  are you";
    String secondValue="HI  How \r are you";
    String thirdValue="HI  How \n are you";         
    System.out.println(val.matches(regExpCharacter));
    System.out.println(secondValue.matches(regExpCharacter));
    System.out.println(thirdValue.matches(regExpCharacter));

}

My output is: true 
              false
              false
```

Why for secondValue and thirdValue variable it prints false even though it matches the  regExpCharacter?

Comment: \r,\n are not covered by .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `.` by default won't match line breaks `\n` or `\r`. So change your regex to,

```
"(?s)(.*)HI(.*)"
```

`(?s)` DOTALL modifier, which makes dot present in your regex to match also the line breaks.

**OR**

```
"([\\s\\S]*?)HI([\\s\\S]*)"
```

`[\s\S]` matches any space or non-space character. `\s` matches line breaks also.

```
String regExpCharacter = "(?s)(.*)HI(.*)";
String val="HI  How  are you";
String secondValue="HI  How \r are you";
String thirdValue="HI  How \n are you";         
System.out.println(val.matches(regExpCharacter));
System.out.println(secondValue.matches(regExpCharacter));
System.out.println(thirdValue.matches(regExpCharacter));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
```

Comment: can u show any example for difference of "(?s)(.*)HI(.*)" and  "([\\s\\S]*?)HI([\\s\\S]*)"

Comment: both ` "(?s)(.*?)HI(.*)" and "([\\s\\S]*?)HI([\\s\\S]*)"` will do the same job.